# Windows Service with Automatic (Delayed Start) fails to open a socket

Tags: windows, sockets, service

I have a Windows Service which recently was set to Automatic(Delayed Start) from Automatic because sometimes it was failing to start and that would have required manual intervention to start it.
But on one of the machines we are testing with the service failed to open a socket on TCP port 5000.
The error is the following:
Initialize(): System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)

- There is a rule on the firewall to allow the service to listen on TCP
  port 5000
- Restarting the service results in the same socket error
- netstat -o does not show any other process listening on TCP port 5000. Only on System start up I had one instance of the following: TCP    [::1]:5000             PrecisionLab01:49844   TIME_WAIT       0

Returning the service to Automatic startup resolves the issue. No other system of our 4 test machines has that problem when the service is set for Automatic (Delayed Start)

Is there a way to diagnose which app is responsible for making the System kernel process to claim TCP port 5000?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I was able to get the following from netstat -o -q that TCP port 5000 is being used by the local system (PID 4): 

TCP    0.0.0.0:5000           PrecisionLab01:0       LISTENING 
      
Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message you quoted is `WSAEACCES`, which is documented for `bind()` under two conditions: 1) "*attempt to bind a datagram socket to the broadcast address failed because the setsockopt option SO_BROADCAST is not enabled.*"; 2) "*another application, service, or kernel mode driver is bound to the same address with exclusive access. Such exclusive access is a new feature of Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later, and is implemented by using the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE option.*" Assuming #2, when set to Automatic, your service likely binds its socket before the other app can bind to the same IP

Comment: You can enumerate the TCP/UDP tables directly, matching up the local IP/port you are interested in, which will tell you the owning process ID if you find a match, and from that you can then the EXE filename that created that PID. See `GetTcpTable2()`, `GetExtendedTcpTable()`, `GetExtendedUdpTable()`, etc on MSDN.

Comment: The owning PID is 4 which is the System kernel process which does not give me enough information to pinpoint an application/driver that has to be uninstalled to free TCP port 5000.

Comment: Here is the output from Powershell:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5000).OwningProcess

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName

-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------

   5012       0      196        676     735.20      4   0 System

Comment: You won't be able to get more fine-grain info about what is actually using the port, sorry.  You are just going to have to use trial-and-error to disable startup items until your service starts working the way you need.

Comment: I disabled one by one all startup items in Task Manager but to no avail. I guess I'll ask IT to rebuild that test machine to rule out it's a particular build that has this issue.Thank you Remy